# Error Custom List Using enumitem

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am trying to create a customised list, but keep on getting an error message. I feel it's best if I post a MWE and a screenshot of the output.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[mylist,1]{
    label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[mylist,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    ref=(\Roman{mylisti}.\roman*)   }
\setlist[mylist,3]{
    label=(\textit{\alph*}),
    ref=(\Roman{mylisti},\roman{mylistii}.\textit{\alph*})  }
\setlist[mylist,4]{
    label=(\arabic*),
    ref=(\Roman{mylisti},\roman{mylistii}.\textit{\alph{mylistiii}}.\arabic*)   }

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
    \item level one, I
    \begin{mylist}
        \item level two, i
        \begin{mylist}
            \item level three, a
            \begin{mylist}
                \item level four, 1
            \end{mylist}
        \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've made custom lists before with `enumitem` with no issues, for example the following runs with no errors.

```
\newlist{my_list}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[my_list,1]{
    label=(\roman*) }
\setlist[my_list,2]{
    label=(\textit{\alph*}),
    ref=(\roman{my_listi}.\textit{\alph*})  }
\setlist[my_list,3]{
    label=\arabic*.,
    ref=(\roman{my_listi}.\textit{\alph{my_listii}}.\arabic*)   }
```

I have played around for ages with the first one, but can't get it to work. I'd be very appreciative of help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to add braces to commas in `ref=`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[mylist,1]{
    label=(\Roman*)}
\setlist[mylist,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    ref=(\Roman{mylisti}.\roman*) }
\setlist[mylist,3]{
    label=(\textit{\alph*}),
    ref=(\Roman{mylisti}{,}\roman{mylistii}.\textit{\alph*}) }
\setlist[mylist,4]{
    label=(\arabic*),
    ref=(\Roman{mylisti}{,}\roman{mylistii}.\textit{\alph{mylistiii}}.\arabic*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
    \item level one, I\label{test-level-i}
    \begin{mylist}
        \item level two, i\label{test-level-ii}
        \begin{mylist}
            \item level three, a\label{test-level-iii}
            \begin{mylist}
                \item level four, 1 \label{test-level-iv}
            \end{mylist}
        \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}
We see in \ref{test-level-iv}…

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. They weren't even supposed to be commas, but fullstops! Can't believe I wasted so long on that =P